# Anyone know how to receive different inputs inside a loop and add them together in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Basically, I am trying to make this menu for a project and I need to make it loop. What I am having difficulty on is trying to take input into a list in a loop. I want the program to add up the totals of every order that is taken and put them into a list. I then want the program to add up this list and give me the final total cost of the order. How would I make it so that I can use a list in a loop without it deleting what was previously inputted in there. For example, if I order a chicken sandwhich the first time in the loop and then order only that again the second time and then quit the loop, instead of showing me a price of 10.50 I only get a total price of 5.25. Thanks for the help!

```
choice = (input("How many people are you ordering for? To quit the program simply type quit."))

while choice != 'quit':

  if Beverage == "yes" and Fries == "yes":
    Total_Cost = CostSandwich + CostBeverage + CostFries - 1 + KetchupNumber
  elif Beverage == "no" and Fries == "no":
    Total_Cost = CostSandwich + CostBeverage + CostFries + KetchupNumber
  elif Beverage == "yes" and Fries == "no":
    Total_Cost = CostSandwich + CostBeverage + CostFries + KetchupNumber
  elif Beverage == "no" and Fries == "yes":
    Total_Cost = CostSandwich + CostBeverage + CostFries + KetchupNumber
  

  print("Your total cost is", Total_Cost)
  print("You ordered a", SandwichType, "Sandwich,", BeverageType, "Beverage,", FriesType, "Fries,", "and", KetchupType, "Ketchup Packets." )

  finalcost = [0]
  finalcost.append(Total_Cost)

  totaloffinalcost = sum(finalcost)

  choice = (input("If you would like to quit then type quit or type anything to continue"))

print("The final cost is", totaloffinalcost)
```

Comment: take  `finalcost = [0]` outside the loop, it will init on each iterataion

Comment: Thanks really helped!!!

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the fact that a lot can be done to improve and make this much efficient, the answer to your query:

*OP:  For example, if I order a chicken sandwhich the first time in the loop and then order only that again the second time and then quit the loop, instead of showing me a price of 10.50 I only get a total price of 5.25.*

That happens because on each iteration inside the while loop just before taking the sum, you're initialing a list:

```
finalcost = [0]
```

Take this outside the while loop:

```
finalcost = [0]
while choice != 'quit':
    # rest of the code
```